# Unable to programmatically scroll to top of ScrollView or SetFocus

Tags: android, scrollview

I have a `ScrollView` with a nested `LinearLayout` that has some length to it. At the bottom I have a button that has a function that will need to act similarly to a `Return to Top`.

I've tried creating an `onClickListener` and with `setFocusableInTouchMode` and `setFocusable` set to true, use the listener to request focus.  No luck.

I've tried the following without success.

`scrollView.smoothScrollTo(0,0);`

`scrollView.fullScroll(scrollView.FOCUS_UP);`

`scrollGetStartedGetMostFromLearning.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_UP);`

**XML**

```
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="Title"
                android:id="@+id/textgTitle"
                android:textColor="#F0F0F0"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnTop"
                android:text="To Top"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/white"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
   </ScrollView>
```

**Java**

```
btnTop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
    scrollView.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_UP);
} //or any of the 3 used above
```

Any help or direction as to what I'm doing wrong is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: try with nested scroll view

Comment: Using a `nestedScrollView` using `scrollView.smoothScrollTo(0,0);` worked. Thanks for the idea Saveen